# Location service: LocationAlways vs LocationWhenInUse

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

Here is a strange behaviour in an iOS app.
This is the code related to my question:

Initializing the Location stuff:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
```

When the Location functionality is requested:

```
if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]!=kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
    // Give a message to the user: NO GPS HERE!
}
```

And inside the app.plist I put a key: `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`, with a string.

For some reason that I do not understand, it does not work. I get told that GPS is not allowed for this app, I have to change the privacy settings, I go and change the privacy settings as requested, I come back and try again, and get the same message …. and get in an infinite loop.

On the other hand if I put a key: `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`, with a string inside the app.plist; not changing anything in the code.
Then my app is allowed to use the Location functionality (LocationAlways).
Though it is better than having no GPS at all, my app ends up by using the -LocationAlways- mode when it would be happy to use the —LocationWhenInUse- mode.

Anyone had the same issue and found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized` is Deprecated in iOS 8

Document

> kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized
>   This app is authorized to use location services.
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
>   Deprecated in iOS 8.0

See the document of the enum,you will know why `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized` works

```
typedef enum {
   kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined = 0,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways = kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse 
} CLAuthorizationStatus;
```

So,**if you request whenInUse**, use this key `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse`